# How to convert an existing pv ami to hvm while taking command line ami in Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

How to convert an existing `pv ami` to `hvm` while taking command line `ami` in Amazon EC2?

We are getting following error;

```
Client.InvalidParameterValue: Invalid value 'ami-ID' for AMI. Can not set kernel on an HVM AMI.
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you have tried and the results you have ?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/q/439976/102883

Comment: improved formatting